# Add autocomplete to search view and search results activity

Tags: android, android-search

I'm following [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html#create-sa) to create the search view on my Android app, however I need to add the autocomplete feature to this search view using the search results activity instead of the dropdown list that people usually suggest on blogs and here on StackOverflow.

You can see an example of what I need on Google Maps (Android), except that they are not using an ActionBar.

How can I do this?

Comment: Hi, So what did you do about this?

Comment: Sorry but I don't remember if I did find a solution.